# I want my mouse to be clicked with a random delay

Tags: mouse

I’ve seen some other forum posts regarding it, but what people have suggested only clicks the mouse with a specific delay. Any way to keep the delay totally random or in a certain range?

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu?

Comment: You *may* be able to wire something up using [mousetweaks](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/mousetweaks.1.html) with the `--ssc-time` option and a cron job that runs at regular intervals that calls a script to adjust the delay to some value between 0.2 and 3.0 seconds ... but I am curious about what sort of use case a person might have to want something like this 

Comment: Thanks man. Actually I’ll be using it in games.

Answer (score 1):

Max Auto Clicker program comes with three (3) types of delays feature :

1. Pre-delay time
2. Random delay time
3. Emulate human click delay

This is a cross-platform program, means that can be install on Linux(Ubuntu) and Windows(Microsoft). To get more information about these delays and settings read [help page](https://maxautoclicker.blogspot.com/2021/05/help-how-to-use-max-auto-clicker.html)

For Linux available .deb, .zip, .AppImage packages. This is the software [download page](https://maxautoclicker.blogspot.com/p/download-maxautoclicker-for-free.html)
and the official website: https://sourceforge.net/projects/maxautoclicker/

If you have anything else, comment bellow.